# Send Messages with Twilio Firebase Extension Invalid Callback URL

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, twilio, firebase-extensions

We are using Firebase and the Twilio extension for Firebase to send text messages from our app and getting a 11200 error. Our callback url is returning a 404 status not found.

See below:

```
Error Details Msg=Request+to+StatusCallback+URL+was+not+successful.&httpResponse=404<html><head> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"> <title>404 Page not found</title> </head> <body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff> <h1>Error: Page not found</h1> <h2>The requested URL was not found on this server.</h2> <h2></h2> </body></html>
```

This url, from what I can tell, is generated by the firebase extension. How can I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you create a firestore function "statusCallback" , it will be hit by Twilio .  Their code creates an incorrectly named extension.

export const statusCallback = functions.https.onRequest(async (req: any, res: any) => {
logger.log("info", "resource info", req.body);
});